# How to lookup and sum with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have this spreadsheet

[image]

And I want to essentially grab the value to the right of the value.

So for example, if I look for `x`, I want to get the values of `E9`, and `E15`. So far this is my query:

```
=LOOKUP(D23 , $D$5:$E$16 , $E$5:$E$16 , FALSE)
```

But all I'm getting is:

```
Error
Formula parse error
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

I thought I might be making a mistake, since I forgot I'd have to `SUM`, but after changing the key to `tax` it still doesn't work

I tried both `LOOKUP` and `VLOOKUP`, same problem in each

I also tried smth I found in a tutorial, but no luck

```
=VLOOKUP(D23 , $D$5:$E$16 , 2 , FALSE)
```

TO FUTURE SEARCHERS:

To figure out which "breaker" you need (`,` of `;`), take a close look at the formula help. It's the blue question mark next to the `fx`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `SUMIF` ([Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en)) instead of `LOOKUP` or `VLOOKUP`.

Like so:

```
=SUMIF(D5:D16;"tax";E5:E16)
```

Also, as you are using a Polish "Locale", you should use `;` instead of `,`.

**Reasoning**: whether you have to use `,` or `;` depends on the "Locale" of the spreadsheet, under File –> Spreadsheet Settings. For example, a US or UK "Locale" would use the former (`,`) while a Hungarian or Polish "Locale" would use the latter (`;`)

Comment: This gives me the same error. Also any idea why my `VLOOKUP` formula is wrong?

Comment: could you share a version of the spreadsheet (without sensitive data) so I could take try to make it work?

Comment: Fair enough :D If your question has been resolved, please mark this thread as "Answered"

Comment: And yes, changing `,` to `;` in your query fixes the problem

Comment: Alright, I'm glad that worked. Just a tip: whether you have to use , or ; depends on the "Locale" of the spreadsheet, under File –> Spreadsheet Settings. For example, a US or UK "Locale" would use the former (,) while a Hungarian or Polish "Locale" would use the latter (;)

Comment: Oh, that's good to know. Can you add it to the answer? Will be helpful for the future users

Answer (score 3):

You should use SUMIF

```
=sumif($D$5:$D$16;"x";$E$5:$E$16)
```

Comment: This gives me the same error. Also any idea why my `VLOOKUP` formula is wrong?